# Oracle Optimization: which execution plan is better?

Tags: oracle, plsql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, nvl

I've to improve this query:

```
    SELECT sub.SDDOCO
    FROM( 
      SELECT SDSHAN, SDDOCO, SDMCU, SDLITM, SDIR03, SDVR01
      FROM PRODDTA.F4211 

      UNION ALL

      SELECT SDSHAN, SDDOCO, SDMCU, SDLITM, SDIR03, SDVR01
      FROM PRODDTA.F42119 
    )sub 
    INNER JOIN PRODDTA.F0101 tab 
         ON sub.SDSHAN = tab.ABAN8
    WHERE 
        sub.SDMCU LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pMCU,SDMCU)),'%') 
    AND sub.SDLITM LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pLITM,SDLITM)),'%') 
    AND sub.SDIR03 LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pIR03,SDIR03)),'%')
    AND tab.ABALKY LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pALKY,ABALKY)),'%')
    AND sub.SDVR01 LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pVR01,SDVR01)),'%')
```

I've modified WHERE conditions in this manner:

```
    ((:pMCU IS NOT NULL AND sub.SDMCU LIKE '%' || :pMCU || '%') OR :pMCU IS NULL)
AND ((:pLITM IS NOT NULL AND sub.SDLITM LIKE '%' || :pLITM || '%') OR :pLITM IS NULL)
AND ((:pIR03 IS NOT NULL AND sub.SDIR03 LIKE '%' || :pIR03 || '%') OR :pIR03 IS NULL)
AND ((:pVR01 IS NOT NULL AND sub.SDVR01 LIKE '%' || :pVR01 || '%') OR :pVR01 IS NULL)
AND ((:pALKY IS NOT NULL AND tab.ABALKY LIKE '%' || :pALKY || '%') OR :pALKY IS NULL)
```

At [this link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoP3TVA0-inWgTPw_l4Kyvwhu55b) you can read the execution plan for both query.
Which one is better?
Any suggestion to improve query?
I need to have all records of result

**EDIT**:
Where "F4211" table has 71,758 records and F42119 has 4,606,154 records

**EDIT**: and F0101 table has 634,187 records.
Whith All parameters sets to NULL, the result is 4,677,925 records in an unreasonable time (some minutes).
The query without where clauses takes 4,677,925 records in 58 seconds

**EDIT**:
Inserting code snippents I exceed max num of char :(
Any suggestion to post execution plan?

**EDIT**:
This is the execution plan:

```
"PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"
"Plan hash value: 3925457500"
" "
"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"| Id  | Operation                              | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |"
"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                  |     2 |  1224 |   614K  (1)| 00:00:24 |"
"|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                          |                  |     2 |  1224 |   614K  (1)| 00:00:24 |"
"|   2 |   VIEW                                 | index$_join$_004 | 31721 |  1455K| 11379   (1)| 00:00:01 |"
"|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                           |                  |       |       |            |          |"
"|   4 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN               | F0101_0          | 31721 |  1455K|  2414   (1)| 00:00:01 |"
"|*  5 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN               | F0101_3          | 31721 |  1455K|  8390   (1)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   6 |   VIEW                                 |                  |     1 |   565 |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   7 |    UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE          |                  |       |       |            |          |"
"|*  8 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| F4211            |     1 |   417 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|*  9 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | F4211_4          |     6 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 10 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| F42119           |     1 |   422 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 11 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | F42119_9         |    10 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
" "
"Predicate Information (identified by operation id):"
"---------------------------------------------------"
" "
"   3 - access(ROWID=ROWID)"
"   5 - filter(""GGG"".""ABALKY"" LIKE U'%'||NVL(:PALKY,""GGG"".""ABALKY"")||U'%')"
"   8 - filter(""SDMCU"" LIKE U'%'||NVL(:PMCU,""SDMCU"")||U'%' AND ""SDLITM"" LIKE "
"              U'%'||NVL(:PLITM,""SDLITM"")||U'%' AND ""SDIR03"" LIKE U'%'||NVL(:PIR03,""SDIR03"")||U'%' AND ""SDVR01"" "
"              LIKE U'%'||NVL(:PVR01,""SDVR01"")||U'%')"
"   9 - access(""SDSHAN""=""GGG"".""ABAN8"")"
"  10 - filter(""SDMCU"" LIKE U'%'||NVL(:PMCU,""SDMCU"")||U'%' AND ""SDLITM"" LIKE "
"              U'%'||NVL(:PLITM,""SDLITM"")||U'%' AND ""SDIR03"" LIKE U'%'||NVL(:PIR03,""SDIR03"")||U'%' AND ""SDVR01"" "
"              LIKE U'%'||NVL(:PVR01,""SDVR01"")||U'%')"
"  11 - access(""SDSHAN""=""GGG"".""ABAN8"")"
```

Comment: (1) You probably cannot easily improve this query.  (2) You should qualify all column names so we know where they are coming from.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thx, I've qualified the columns

Comment: How many rows have the tables? Do you need all rows at one moment (ALL ROWS / FIRST ROWS)?

Comment: @PetrPribyl: thx, I've added rows number

Comment: How many rows has F0101 table?

Comment: and PRODDTA.F0101?

Comment: how long running the query now ? and how many rows has the resultset?

Comment: @Thomas: i'ts all? You need other info?

Comment: Avoid leading '%' in your `like` conditions if possible. Opromizer then can use possible indexes. There is not much more to do. If you need to select by pacticular word in text, use fulltext index.

Comment: Oh, so you want us to open documents posted by someone we don't know on some website somewhere? Not a chance!

Comment: @mathguy: the documents are a Export to html of execution plan made with sqlDeveloper :)

Comment: @GlaucoCucchiar - you are missing my point. I am sure that is true, but how do I know you aren't an Australian hacker wanting me to open some documents I don't know anything about? That's not how you post execution plans on SO. Copy them and paste them right into your post.

Comment: Please paste your query plans directly into your question.  This will make sure that future readers will be able to see them, and so that we don't have to open unknown documents on unknown websites.

Comment: I've tried to post execution plan in post, but I exceeded maximum number of chars!! (30,000 vs 120,000). Have you a suggestion to post execution plan?

Answer (score 1):

1 Oracle have good facilities for improve query performance for example DBMS_SQLTUNE https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_sqltune.htm#TGSQL586
At the begin you may create tuning task

```
declare
  l_task_name varchar2(4000);
begin
 l_task_name := DBMS_SQLTUNE.CREATE_TUNING_TASK(
      sql_text => q'!SELECT sub.SDDOCO
FROM( 
  SELECT SDSHAN, SDDOCO, SDMCU, SDLITM, SDIR03, SDVR01
  FROM PRODDTA.F4211 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SDSHAN, SDDOCO, SDMCU, SDLITM, SDIR03, SDVR01
  FROM PRODDTA.F42119 
)sub 
INNER JOIN PRODDTA.F0101 tab 
     ON sub.SDSHAN = tab.ABAN8
WHERE 
    sub.SDMCU LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pMCU,SDMCU)),'%') 
AND sub.SDLITM LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pLITM,SDLITM)),'%') 
AND sub.SDIR03 LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pIR03,SDIR03)),'%')
AND tab.ABALKY LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pALKY,ABALKY)),'%')
AND sub.SDVR01 LIKE  CONCAT(CONCAT('%',nvl(:pVR01,SDVR01)),'%')!'
, bind_list   => sql_binds( anydata.ConvertVarchar2('ABC'), 
            anydata.ConvertVarchar2('BCD'),
            anydata.ConvertVarchar2('CDE'),
            anydata.ConvertVarchar2('DEF'),
            anydata.ConvertVarchar2('EFG'))
, task_name   => 'TEST_TUNING_SQL_SO' 
, description => 'Task to tune a query from StackOverflow');
end;
/
```

After you may execute it

```
begin
  DBMS_SQLTUNE.EXECUTE_TUNING_TASK (
   task_name => 'TEST_TUNING_SQL_SO');
end;
/
```

And retrieve report and perform advices

```
select DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_TUNING_TASK(
   task_name => 'TEST_TUNING_SQL_SO') from dual;
```

2 How to publicate a plan

You may generate it in text format(not in HTML). And try to add only plan table with information about predicates. You may exclude any additional information if it was not required.

Comment: (1) - thks, but I've recieved this error: ORA-13616: The current user has not been granted the ADVISOR privilege. (2) - SqlDeveloper don't generate plan in text.

Comment: (2) Simple example for SQLPLUS `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM dual;` and after `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);` I think it work in SQL developer too

Comment: could you gather_table_stats for queried tables? for example `begin DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('PRODDTA', 'F4211') ; end. And check are plan change or not?